# In Angular 14, how do I include a child component in a standalone component?

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I have a standalone component in which I want to include a child component from another module.  The standalone component looks like

```
<div>
    <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

and its service file is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MyModule
  ]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  ...
}
```

The child component is in another module -- MyModule.  The my.module.ts file looks like

```
/* imports */

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class MyModule { 
  constructor(entityDefinitionService: EntityDefinitionService) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But my parent's HTML is giving me the error on the

```
    <child-component></child-component>
```

line ...

```
'app-child-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-child-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-child-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to export `ChildComponent` from the `MyModule`, so you can use it somewhere else:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [ ChildComponent ]
})
export class MyModule { 
  constructor(entityDefinitionService: EntityDefinitionService) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you are not using **app.module.ts** or you are in *version **17*** and above you can try or fix this by using this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MyModule,
    ChildComponent. // add here your child component 

  ]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  ...
}
```